# Get all Nodes that don't have a specific relationship in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to get all Nodes (node1) that have relationship (relationship of type R1) to node2 and not having (relationship of type R2).
I tried to run this query :

```
MATCH  node1 -[r1: R1]-> node2 WHERE node2.id = '1234' WITH node1,node2
OPTIONAL MATCH  node1- [r2: R2]->node2 WHERE r2 is NULL 
RETURN content
```

I am stil getting nodes that have r2 relationship in the resulte.
what is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you want is `MATCH` syntax in the `WHERE` in a `NOT`:

```
MATCH  (node1)-[:R1]->(node2)
WHERE node2.id = '1234' AND NOT (node1)-[:R2]->(node2)
RETURN node1
```